# sqlite3 one to one join

Tags: join, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tbA (
       columnA TEXT
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE tbB (
       columnB TEXT
)
```

`tbA` has these records:

```
A1
A2
A3
```

and
`tbB` has these records:

```
B1
B2
B3
```

How can I retrieve records from both tables while they are matched one to one? I mean if I search for `A1` which has `ROWID` of 1 in `tbA`, it match the record with the same `ROWID` from `tbB` which is `B1`

what I have tried so far:

```
select * from tbA cross join tbB where columnA = "A1"
```

but the result is:

```
1.>    A1    B1
2.>    A1    B2
```

I just need first row(equal `ROWID` in both table) and not the subsequent rows;

Comment: You do not show any `rowid`.

Comment: you mean for contents of the tables?

Comment: I mean the `rowid`s that you mention in your question.

Comment: `match the record with the same ROWID from tbB` -> `where tbA._id = tbB._id`

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to create a new column, you can easily join row of two table one by one.

```
CREATE TABLE tbA (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, columnA TEXT);
CREATE TABLE tbB (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, columnB TEXT);

INSERT INTO tbA (columnA) values ("A1");
INSERT INTO tbA (columnA) values ("A2");
INSERT INTO tbA (columnA) values ("A3");
INSERT INTO tbB (columnB) values ("B1");
INSERT INTO tbB (columnB) values ("B2");
INSERT INTO tbB (columnB) values ("B3");

SELECT tbA.columnA, tbB.columnB FROM tbA, tbB WHERE tbA.id=tbB.id;
A1|B1
A2|B2
A3|B3
```

Comment: there is always a rowid column in sqlite, whether you declare it explicitly or not. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: can we use the implicit rowid column without declaring a new PRIMARY KEY(id in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help;

found it; without declaring an explicit column as a PRIMARY KEY and using the implicit `rowid` column:

```
SELECT * FROM tbA, tbB WHERE tbA.columnA="A1" and tbA.rowid=tbB.rowid
```